# Probability questions based on mutual exclusion

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I'm appearing for an exam for which I'm giving mock tests, however I came across this particular question that I'm unable to solve, it says:

> A certain experiment has three possible outcomes. The outcomes are mutually exclusive and have probabilities $p$, $\frac{p}{2}$ and $\frac{p}{4}$ respectively. What is the value of $p$?

How do I approach this problem? I know what mutually exclusive events are but I don't know how to start, any heads-up on this? And would someone give a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the events are mutually exclusive (i.e. two events can't both happen) and there are only three outcomes then the three probabilities are collectively exhaustive (i.e. they represent all possible outcomes) and therefore must sum to $1$. Hence $$p + \frac{p}{2} + \frac{p}{4} = \frac{7}{4}p = 1$$

and therefore $$p = \frac{4}{7}$$